# Why this `case` is a must needed?

Tags: scala, case

```
object Test1 {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val list = List("a", "b")
        list map { x ⇒ println(x) }
        list map { case x ⇒ println(x) }

        val list2 = List(("aa", "11"))
        list2 map {
            case (key, value) ⇒ println("key: "+key+", value: "+value)
        }
    }

}
```

Please note the last line, why the keyword `case` must be used, but the `list map { x ⇒ println(x) }` can remove it?

Comment: I removed my misleading answer as it didn't compile as you noted, sorry about that, I had no compiler handy :(

Comment: The `case` looks like boilerplate, sure. The real question here is: why does the compiler not try what happens with a `case` if it finds something weird instead of a parameter identifier? Maybe because you can do only so much implicitly without confusing everybody.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{ case (key, value) => f }
```

is not the same thing as

```
{ (key, value) => f }
```

The first is a pattern match that breaks a `Tuple2` into its components, assigning their values to `key` and `value`. In this case, only one parameter is being passed (the tuple). `{ x => println(x) }` works because `x` is assigned the tuple, and `println` prints it.

The second is a function which takes two parameters, and makes no pattern matching. Since `map` requires a function which takes a single parameter, the second case is incompatible with `map`.

Comment: For those wanting chapter and verse, see section 8.5, "Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions", in the [Book of Martin](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf‎).

Answer (score 14):

You can't break open the tuple in function literal. That's why you'll have to use case to match them instead. Another way is using **tupled** to make your function with two arguments fit:

```
import Function.tupled 
list2 map tupled {
  (key, value) => println("key: "+key+", value: "+value)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`list2` has elements of type `Tuple2[Int, Int]`, so the signature of the function you have to pass map (in this case ... `foreach` is a more natural choice when you don't return something) is `Tuple2[Int, Int] => Unit`.  Which is to say, it takes a single argument of type `Tuple2[Int, Int]`.

Since Tuple2 supports `unapply`, you can use pattern matching to break apart that tuple within your function, as you did:

```
{
  case (key, value) ⇒ println("key: "+key+", value: "+value)
}
```

The signature of this function is still `Tuple2[Int, Int] => Unit`

It is identical to, and probably compiles to the same bytecodes, as:

```
{
  x: Tuple2[Int, Int] => println("key: "+x._1+", value: "+x._2)
}
```

This is one of so many examples where Scala combines orthogonal concepts in a very pleasing way.

Answer (score 3):

`list2 map { x => println(x) }` works without problems for me. If you want to have pattern matching (splitting your argument in its parts according to its structure) you need always `case`. Alternatively you can write:

```
list2 map { x => println("key: "+x._1+", value: "+x._2) }
```

BTW, `map` should be used to *transform* a list in another one. If you just want to go through all elements of a list, use `foreach` or for comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning Scala, but I believe what's happening is that you've defined a partial function taking one argument. When invoking methods such as List.map or List.foreach that only require one argument you can omit the underscore or named val.

Example ommitting val name in closure:

```
val v = List("HEY!", "BYE!")
v.foreach { Console.println } // Pass partial function, automatically
```

This is the same as:

```
val v = List("HEY!", "BYE!")
v.foreach { Console.println _ } // Pass partial function, explicitly
```

Using the anonymous val:

```
val v = List("HEY!", "BYE!")
v.foreach { Console.println(_) } // Refer to anonymous param, explicitly
```

Or using a named val:

```
val v = List("HEY!", "BYE!")
v.foreach { x => Console.println(x) } // Refer to val, explicitly
```

In your closure you use a partial function (the case statement) that takes an anonymous variable and immediately turns it into a tuple bound to two separate variables.

I imagine I goofed up on one of the snippets above. When I get to my work computer I will verify in the REPL.

Also, take a look at [Function Currying in Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala) for some more info.

Comment: What makes them partial functions?

Comment: @Eric With case, you're doing pattern matching, which might not match.

Comment: If I define: `val f: (Int, Int) => Unit  = { case (x: Int, y: Int) => println(x) }`, then ask, `f.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[(Int, Int),Unit]]`, the answer is false.  I don't believe it is a partial function, it's pattern matching inside a normal function.

Comment: Ok, I see, it is a partial function, but not a PartialFunction.